# Initialising std::discrete_distribution in VS2013

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, std

I have a `std::vector<float> weights;` containing the list of weights. I don't know what will be in this list until some stage in running the program. I would like to do

```
std::discrete_distribution<> dist(weights.begin(),weights.end());
```

but VS2013 doesn't appear to have a constructor for std::discrete_distribution that accepts an iterator range. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compare [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution) and the [Microsoft reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462326.aspx) for `std::discrete_distribution`:

These are the constructors provided by VS2013:

```
discrete_distribution();
explicit discrete_distribution(
    const param_type& par0
);
discrete_distribution(
    initializer_list<double> IList
);
template<class Fn>
    discrete_distribution(
        size_t count,
        double low, 
        double high, 
        Fn func
);
```

There is one important constructor missing, probably because the Microsoft developers didn't have the time to implement it:

```
template< class InputIt >
 discrete_distribution( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

That means, unless the documentation is incomplete, you simply can't use an iterator-based constructor for this class. Switch to another compiler (like clang or g++), or wait until this feature is implemented.

Now for a workaround you can use right now:

```
std::size_t i(0);
assert( !weights.empty() ); // No weights would be very weird.
std::discrete_distribution<> dist(weights.size(),
                                  0.0, // dummy!
                                  0.0, // dummy!
                                  [&weights,&i](double)
{
   auto w = weights[i];
   ++i;
   return w;
 });
```

I hope that at least lambdas are supported ;-) The important thing is to capture `i` by reference, such that it gets properly incremented. Demo: http://ideone.com/nIBUts

Why does this work? The constructor we are using here is:

```
template< class UnaryOperation >
discrete_distribution( std::size_t count, double xmin, double xmax,
                       UnaryOperation unary_op );
```

The [documentation on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution) tells us that the `count` (in our case `weights.size()`), as well as the `xmin` and `xmax` is used to create the weights using the `UnaryOperation`.

We are *ignoring* `xmin` and `xmax` on purpose. As the `UnaryOperation` we use the lambda

```
[&weights,&i](double)
{
   auto w = weights[i];
   ++i;
   return w;
 }
```

or

```
[&weights,&i](double)
{
   return weights[i++];
}
```

if you prefer.

Now, we are **ignoring** the input value for that operator and just return the i^th element of our vector. We capture both the vector and the index by reference to avoid copies.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough - I know VS2013 is missing this iterator-based constructor. I am looking for some sort of workaround, which isn't just switching compilers or waiting.

Comment: @pighead10 See my edit. Something along these lines should work. I haven't tested it yet though (no compiler on this machine). [Update] at least it compiles with g++-4.7

Comment: You can simplify the lambda to just `[&weights,&i](double){ return weights[i++]; }`.

Comment: @Jaxan I don't consider that an improvement / simplification. Yes, it's less code, but the resulting machine will be identical. Hence, I follow my personal rule of thumb of never doing more than one thing in a line. For me, the access to the element is a separate thing from the iteration, therefore it should be separated for maximum clarity.

Comment: Ok, this is a matter of taste, as I find your code kind of obfuscated: it gives me the impression it does a lot, because there are 3 lines. Besides that, I think that `array[i++]` or `*it++ = ...` occurs often enough that it is very clear to people. Thanks for the quick reply :).

Comment: Now that I think of your above answer, I have a more relevant question. What exactly is the relation between the minimum and weights.front() (and max / back())? I mean, it could be that weights.back() is smaller than weights.front(), right?

Comment: @Jaxan Ugh, right, that's a flaw in my answer. Let me fix that asap. It's actually just an issue of naming (minimum and maximum won't be actually used as minimum and maximum!).

Comment: @Jaxan I've updated the answer to be more precise and also included the shorter version of the lambda. Any comments? :-)

Comment: @stefan Thanks! It's good like it is now. (Also thanks for fixing this problem, it is a shame VS2013 does not include the easiest constructor to use ;-).)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::discrete_distribution<> dist(
    weights.size(), 
    -0.5, 
    -0.5+weights.size(), 
    [&weights](size_t i) 
    { 
        return weights[i]; 
    });
```

or in terms of iterators:

```
//replacement code for: std::discrete_distribution<> dist(first, last);
auto first = weights.cbegin();
auto last = weights.cend();
auto count = std::distance(first, last);
std::discrete_distribution<> dist(
    count, 
    -0.5, 
    -0.5+count, 
    [&first](size_t i) 
    { 
        return *std::next(first,i); 
    });
```

This avoids having to capture a mutable `i` variable. The parameter passed to the lambda can be used as the index.