# Creating a custom interated discrete evolutionary distribution

Tags: c++, distribution

I have been tackling this issue for days now. I am running an evolutionary model which uses a distribution for interactions between species. I pasted the function here. I need to use the template:

`template <class InputIt>`

The function does not recognize the template if I paste it directly before the function declaration. If I paste it before main(), the template is recognized, but I get the single error:

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

The code:

```
void evolution(TeamArray& teamData)
{

default_random_engine randomGenerator((unsigned int)time(NULL));
uniform_int_distribution<int> rand120(0, 120);

int* RandA;
int* RandB;

RandA = new int[rounds];
RandB = new int[rounds];
// Time Period 1

for (int i = 0; i < rounds / 10; ++i)
{
    RandA[i] = rand120(randomGenerator); // generates random numbers from 0 to 120 (121 elements)
}

for (int i = 0; i < rounds / 10; ++i)
{
    RandB[i] = rand120(randomGenerator); // generates random numbers from 0 to 120 (121 elements)
}

for (int i = 0; i < rounds / 10; i++)
{
    interact(teamData[RandA[i]], teamData[RandB[i]]);
}

delete[] RandA;
delete[] RandB;

    // Later time periods (ERA 2 through 10)

// The inside of this loop does the rest of the interactions 
for (int t = 1; t < 10; ++t) // looping through the ERA's
{
    // Intializing distribution 
    std::vector< int> weights(121);
    for (int i = 0; i < 121; i++)
    {
        weights[i] = (teamData[i]).S();
    }

    std::discrete_distribution<int&> dist(weights.begin(), weights.end());

    for (int i = t* (rounds / 10); i < (t+1) * (rounds / 10); ++i)
    {
        RandA[i] = dist(randomGenerator); 
    }

    for (int i = t* (rounds / 10); i < (t + 1) * (rounds / 10); ++i)
    {
        RandB[i] = dist(randomGenerator); 
    }

    for (int i = t* (rounds / 10); i < (t + 1) * (rounds / 10); ++i)
    {
        interact(teamData[RandA[i]], teamData[RandB[i]]);
    }

    delete[] RandA;
    delete[] RandB;
}
```

Comment: The [constructor of `std::discrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) takes only one argument. You are giving it two arguments.

Comment: Ok. So how would I input the weights vector? I also tried this: std::discrete_distribution<int&> dist(weights);

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understands the intricacies of random number generators well enough to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is reported by the linker because a method (in this case the constructor) is called with a signature that does not match any of the specialisations in the class.

The [std::discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution) documentation indicates that there are 4 specialised constructors available and these may cover the case that you require.

The one that you appear closest to the one you attempted to call requires `[InputInterator][2]` references, not `integer` bounds.

The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959404/initialising-stddiscrete-distribution-in-vs2013) for Visual C++ indicates that this constructor is not available on the Microsoft platform but provides an equivalent solution with lower and upper bounds.

Comment: I am new to programming. I know a bit about references. How do I use [InputInterator][2] references in the discrete_distribution?

Comment: does anyone else know this? I am desperate to figure this out.